# Daemon Starting as Root

Tags: launchd

I created a plist for a service I'm trying to run. In it, I put:

```
<key>UserName</key>
<string>_mydaemon</string>
```

For some reason, the daemon starts as root rather than as _mydaemon. Any ideas where to look to figure out what's going on?

Comment: Are you using `StandardOutPath` or `StandardErrorPath`? If so, please check if your `_mydaemon` has an access there.

Comment: I wasn't logging. I'm trying to now. Not getting any log files getting created upon restart or manual launchctl commands. Requires some work to get this working it seems.

Comment: Where are you saving the configuration plist, and how are you loading it?